prevent sending multiple emails within a 30-second interval, multi instances requests
i have written api:
In a Spring application with multiple app instances, for each email, only allow sending the mail within 30 seconds. For the same email, it will be blocked from sending within 30 seconds. However, if it is a different email, it can still be sent normally. If requests for the same email come from two different instances, the request that arrives later will still be blocked, while requests for different emails will be sent normally.
I've tried
@Service
public class EmailService {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private static final int EMAIL_SEND_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 30;

    @Autowired
    public EmailService(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void sendEmail(String email, String message) {
        String sql = "SELECT sent_time FROM email_history WHERE email = ? ORDER BY sent_time DESC LIMIT 1";
        Long lastEmailSentTime = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{email}, Long.class);

        if (lastEmailSentTime != null) {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = (currentTime - lastEmailSentTime) / 1000;

            if (elapsedTime < EMAIL_SEND_INTERVAL_SECONDS) {
                throw new EmailSendingException("Chờ ít nhất " + EMAIL_SEND_INTERVAL_SECONDS + " giây trước khi gửi email tiếp theo.");
            }
        }

      

        String insertSql = "INSERT INTO email_history (email, sent_time) VALUES (?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(insertSql, email, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}

However, it doesn't address the issue of spamming the database multiple times instead of spamming the mail. Users can still spam the database multiple times. Which solution for this?
